# How to block unwanted hosts in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-authz-host

These `.htaccess` rules work:

```
<RequireAll>
Require all granted
Require not ip 1.22.333.444
.
.
.
</RequireAll>
```

These `.htaccess` rules don't work:

```
<RequireAll>
Require all granted
.
.
.
Require not host bad_host
</RequireAll>
```

These `.htaccess` rules don't work as well:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} (163data|amazonaws|colocrossing|poneytel) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

I wrote into the `.htaccess` file at the top:

```
HostnameLookups On
```

The result was an error message, because this command is not allowed in `.htaccess`. So I removed this statement.

In Apache, there is a "remote_host" corresponds to a certain IP.
I want tp prevent unwanted hosts to visit my site, such as spammers or such which generate much useless traffic in my site.

What is wrong in the code example above?

Comment: Explain what exactly you are trying to prevent.

Comment: I want to prevent unwanted hosts visiting my website.

Comment: How do you define a "host" exactly and why are they unwanted?

Comment: The visitor of my site has an IP, and to the IP corresponds a "REMOTE_HOST" in Apache.
The IP / remote_host is unwanted if it is e.g. a spammer or makes useless traffic in my site.

Comment: Logfile example:
Remote Host = aftr-62-216-208-229.dynamic.xxx-online.de
IP  = 62.216.000.999

Comment: @josefus, could you please do mention on what will be the logic to understand if an IP is spam or not? As it's not clear as of now.

Comment: You need to include the actual directives, IPs and hostnames in order to check your rules. However, `HostnameLookups` is required (in your server config) for `REMOTE_HOST` to be set. But note that this puts more work on your server - which is why this is disabled by default and often disabled (permanently) on shared hosts.

Answer (score 0):

`HostnameLookups` needs to be set in the *server config* for the `REMOTE_HOST` server variable to be set. This cannot be set in `.htaccess` (as you have found). This is `Off` by default and is often permanently disabled on shared hosts for performance reasons.

However, `Require [not] host bad_host` is not dependent on `HostnameLookups` being set, so should still work (providing the host has not disabled this in some way). Note that `bad_host` allows partial matches, matched from the *end* and only complete host segments are matched. eg. `ample.com` and `foo.bar.example` will not match **`foo.bar.example.com`**, but `example.com` and `bar.example.com` will.

Note that `Require [not] host` causes Apache to perform a "double reverse DNS lookup". First the hostname is looked up (reverse DNS lookup) from the client IP address and then there is a forward lookup on the hostname to check that the IP address matches. If this does not match then the check fails.

Maybe a `forward-dns` only check is sufficient (requires Apache 2.4.19)? This only performs the reverse DNS lookup to get the hostname. The hostname is not validated.

For example:

```
Require not forward-dns example.com
```

Comment: Thx for the information about  "Requ... not host".  "Requ... not forward-d.." does not work, too. I think that this has the same rule as  "Requ... not host".
As shown in my text above, "RewriteCon. %{REM....." does not work, too. I will try it with the rule "from right".